# JQuery append() information remains even after hard refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made an Ajax call using JQuery and appended (using div.append()) the returned information to a div. This Ajax call was called when clicking on another div on the page. But even after a hard refresh in multiple browsers, the appended information from the previous call stays there, furthermore some of the links in the div it was appended to don't work. I also tried clearing the cache on both the browsers and the server but it didn't work(and found out that they don't store cache on the server).

If it means anything at all, here is the code I used, which I have since commented out:

```
$("#LogoutDiv").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'header.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      NumLgtRqt: 1
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#HeaderContainer").append(response);
      window.location.replace("index.php");
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: *the appended information from the previous call stays there*, this can't happen without the server updating something in the database and then render the page the next time based on these new values. So the problem should be in `header.php` where the request is processed and where, I assume, the `#HeaderContainer` is generated.

Comment: Why are you even appending something to the header container if immediately navigating away from that page afterwards?

Comment: Bergi--it's the logout function----and I was outputting some values to check what they were in the php. I added the navigating away part later.

Comment: Emiel: thank you, I will contact the hosting provider

Comment: Actually, Emiel, the HeaderContainer is not generated in the php

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I put script tags in the append () function. Even though they were inside the append output and in quotations, they still registered to the html.